# Show that the survival probability $\gamma$ satisfies $ \gamma = 1 - e^{-\lambda \gamma} $

Tags: probability, generating-functions, poisson-distribution, random-graphs

The offspring distribution $X$ of a branching process is given by Poisson($\lambda$).
I need to show that the survival probability $\gamma$ satisfies the following equation:

$$ \gamma = 1 - e^{-\lambda \gamma}  $$

Now suppose $\kappa$ is the extinction probability, then it is the smallest solution in $[0,1]$ of the equation $$\kappa = G_X(\kappa) = \mathbb{E}[X^\kappa]$$ where $G_X$ is the probability generating function of $X$.

Since $\kappa = 1 - \gamma$ , therefore $$1- \gamma = G_X(1-\gamma)$$ $$ \space \space \space  = \mathbb{E}[X^{1-\gamma}]$$ $$= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^{1-\gamma} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^i}{i !}$$
This implies, $$\gamma = 1 - e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^{1-\gamma} \frac{\lambda^i}{i !}$$ Now, how do I show $$e^{-\lambda \gamma} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^{1-\gamma} \frac{\lambda^i}{i !}$$ 
Is my approach corret or something wrong with it?

Comment: Using $$G_X(\kappa)=E(\kappa^X)$$ instead of the wrong formula in your post, might help.

Comment: @Did Oh thanks! Blunder! But what kind of distribution does this r.v. $(1-\gamma)^X$ follows?

Comment: What? Simply compute $E(\kappa^X)$ using the distribution of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The extinction probability P is the smallest solution $s = G(s)$, $s \in [0,1]$, and the survival probability is $\gamma = 1-P$.

For Poisson, $G(s) = e^{-\lambda(1-s)}$, thus

$s = e^{-\lambda(1-s)}$.

Since $P$ is the smallest solution of $s$, we make $P=s$ and substitute $\gamma$, leading to the final answer.

$P = e^{-\lambda(1-P)}$

$1-\gamma = e^{-\lambda(1-(1-\gamma))}$

$\gamma = 1-e^{-\lambda\gamma}$.